# Parsing XML in Python using Expat

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xmlnode, expat-parser

Background:  I'm coming from C#-land, so I'm looking for something like being able to handle nodes and values by selecting via Xpath.

Here's my code, so far:

```
import urllib
import sys
from xml.parsers import expat

url = 'http://SomeWebService.SomeDomain.com'
u = urllib.urlopen(url)

Parser = expat.ParserCreate()
data = u.read()
try:
    Parser.Parse(data)
except:
    print "ERROR: Can't parse the XML"
    sys.exit(0)
```

What standard lib should I be using to deal with DOM elements as objects along with their attributes as one could in C#?

I'm looking for something like NodeList nodes = Parser.SelectNodes("Xpath")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have more luck if you tried using one of the `xml.dom` packages, or [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree). ElementTree has some limited xpath support, so if that's what you're used to, it might be the best choice.

Comment: I'm looking here:  http://bit.ly/baRkvP, and I don't see a listing of the different XML DOM implementations.  Can you point me to one or more list(s) of the available xml.dom pkgs (and hopefully include some links to examples)?

Comment: The next two chapters in the manual you linked to covers `xml.dom.minidom`[1] and `xml.dom.pulldom`[2]. I can't think of any examples at the moment, but it should be fairly natural if you're used to working with DOM manipulation. That said, I recommend ElementTree if it can satisfy your needs.



    [1]: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html
    [2]: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.pulldom.html